# Change function to class view django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm doing a django app and at first I've done methods to my view, but I'd like now to change to class.

Here's an exemple of how I tried :

```
def register(response):
if response.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/login")
else:
    form = RegisterForm()

return render(response, "register/register.html", {"form":form})
```

And tried to change like this :

```
class RegisterView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/login")
        else:
            form = RegisterForm()
        return render(response, "register/register.html", {"form":form})
```

But I keep getting a 405 Error Method not allowed, I guess it's because I'm not doing right the changing from method to class.
Any idea ?

Comment: You need to define a `get` method. The same way you have a `post` method

Comment: and what does that method returns ?

Comment: @David check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the get method as well. Below is the code that must do the job

```
class RegisterView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/login")
        else:
            form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, "register/register.html", {"form":form})

    def get(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, "register/register.html", {"form":form})
```

Comment: thank you sir it's working, only had to change *response* to *request* !

Comment: my bad! i made the change from response to request. You can accept the answer if it worked

Comment: no problem, will accept in 5 minutes I have to wait since I created a few minutes ago